# Перенос Windows Server 2016 на новые диски

Tags: сервер, резервное-копирование, raid

Помогите решить следующую задачу:
Есть Windows Server 2016, установлен на RAID 10: 4 диска SSD подключенные к контроллеру Adaptec ASR8805E. Необходимо заменить старые диски SSD на новые бОльшего объема.
Хотел сделать это так:

1. С помощью Acronis True Image делаю бекап всех разделов с этого RAID на другой носитель (и вот тут уже возникла проблема).
2. Выключаю сервер, снимаю старые диски, ставлю новые. Создаю новый RAID.
3. С помощью Acronis True Image восстанавливаю разделы, при этом изменяя их размеры как мне нужно.

По п.1 - загружаюсь с флешки в Acronis PE, нажимаю Load Drivers и загружаю драйвер для моего RAID-контроллера. Весь RAID разбит на 4 раздела: С - на нем стоит ВинСервер; D - там находятся пользовательские данные; 2 раздела без букв, созданных автоматически при установке системы. Если я пытаюсь забекапить весь диск, то Акронис создает некоторое время, а потом показывает ошибку.
Из этого делаю вывод, что выбранное мной ПО не подходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом реализовать описанную выше задачу. И может я в порядке действий ошибаюсь?